# Display Progress bar on post back in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, download, progress-bar, postback

I have a web page in which a button is used to retrieve a large set of data.

I need to show a progress bar image while the button click operation is in progress.

As in button click I was downloading the data, I was in a situation that I could not use update panel and Progress bar asp control.

I have tried with jquery and Css.
It displays the image when button is clicked but not disappearing after the click event is completed.

Html:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnGenReport" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Generate" OnClick="btnGenReport_Click" OnClientClick="ProgressBar()"></asp:LinkButton>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ProgressBar(){
        ShowProgress(function(){
            HideProgress();
        });
    }

    function ShowProgress(callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0) + 93;
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);

        callback();
    }

    function HideProgress(){
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.css("display","none");
    }
</script>
```

Please help to get the Progress bar.....

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: In your jquery code, nothing tells when the loading is complete. Also, you should clear your timer in the `HideProgress` function.

Comment: To hide the Progress bar I have set it inside ProgressBar() in Jquery ie. after showProgress() func completes, the HideProgress() will be called. If I remove setTimeout the progress bar shows and hide immediately before the data retrieve completes. If not the Progress bar is not disappearing...

Answer (score 0):

set timeout is asynchroneous. so, in your ShowProgress function, the first thing done is HideProgress and then, 200ms later, show the progressbar.

EDIT :

```
function myFunction()
{
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
    alert("foo");
}
```

Try it yourself !

I assume that you are using the timer to simulate the server working. When you will send your data to your server with ajax, you'll be able to use a dedicated callback function that will be called after the ajax call to be performed.

So, or you try it directly with ajax either you must find an other solution for simulate delay.